# OSX Mountain Lion & Applescript - Finder 'steals' focus

Tags: applescript, osx-mountain-lion, finder

I've searched high and low to find a solution for this but have come up trumps.

I have a simple Applescript to wait for a minute, before opening a browser in fullscreen mode. (Allowing MAMP to startup as well).

The problem I face is, "Finder" has focus, and when the Applescript goes to execute the fullscreen command 'keystroke f {command down, shift down} it opens the "All Files" dialog, rather than the desired, Browser focused, enter fullscreen.

Does anyone know how to get around this please?

Comment: Solved! I added:
keystroke tab using {command down}
delay 1
keystroke "f" using {command down, shift down}

...therefore effectively shifting the focus to my browser, and then doing the keystrokes to invoke the fullscreen mode! Think boy, THINK!

Answer (score 0):

```
keystroke tab using {command down} 
delay 1 
keystroke "f" using {command down, shift down}
```

This works in my instance as the Finder had focus, and the next open application was my browser, which was the one I wanted to have focus. So if I were to do this manually I would hold COMMAND and press TAB once, to get the focus of the 'next app'

I'm not sure that the delay is required, but I added a 1 second delay just to make sure that the browser had focus, and then I execute the keystrokes to invoke fullscreen mode!

Comment: Would you consider adding some narrative to explain why this code works, and what makes it an answer to the question? This would be very helpful to the person asking the question, and anyone else who comes along.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you also activate the target application before entering full screen?

```
delay 10
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    reopen
end
tell application "System Events" to tell window 1 of process "Safari"
    perform action "AXPress" of (button 1 where subrole is "AXFullScreenButton")
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Lauri, I believe I already had the application activated, from memory...
    delay 60
    tell application "Firefox" to activate
        keystroke "f" using {command down, shift down}
    end tell

...Either way, Finder would have the focus and from what I've read it seems to be a Lion/Mountain Lion 'issue'. Hence I came up with issuing the keystrokes to do a CMD+TAB to select the application I wanted!